# Soap ui query results as input to another step

Tags: soapui

I have a step in soap ui that is a query. How can I force the next step to use the result of the query as input?
I have the steps ready and I can't figure out how to link them.

Comment: Do you have the Pro version or the free and do you want to use the entire response(which is probably an XML) in your next step or only some of the values?

Comment: Actually I already found the answer. But for everyone else if you want to post an answer, I'm using the free version and the response is indeed in XML. I want only specific values from that response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry it took me such a long time to post an answer here.

I think there are three ways you can extract data from the JDBC step.

1. Using a property transfer step
   In this approach you would create a property transfer step after the jdbc step, give the source as the JDBC step and source property as ResponseAsXml(there will be only one property in the drop down) and use an xpath to extract the specific value you need.

Something like...

```
//Root/NextChildNode/..../ElementYouNeed
```

1. Using groovy, specifically XmlSlurper.
   In this approach, you will treat the JDBC response as any other XML and extract the data you want.

For example..

```
def jdbcXml = context.expand('${getDataFromExcel#ResponseAsXml}')
//display information for all rows
root.ResultSet.Row.each{ row ->
    log.info row["USERS.USER_ID"]
    log.info row["USERS.FNAME"]
    log.info row["USERS.LNAME"]
}
//Where user_id, fname and lname are nodes in the response xml
```

1. Lastly you can directly access the element if you provide the xpath along with the variable.

Something like...

```
String lname

lname = context.expand('${getDataFromExcel#ResponseAsXml#//ResultSet/Row[2]/USERS.LNAME}')

log.info "Last name from second row: " + lname
```

For anyone interested, i [wrote a blog about this too](http://abhishekasthana.com/extract-data-from-jdbc-step/).